# Solaris SMF Syntax

Tags: solaris, xml, smf

I'm trying to write a SMF manifest but i'm stuck because i can't find the complete documentation. Their DTD (`/usr/share/lib/xml/dtd/service_bundle.dtd.1`) is a joke, it's full of CDATA.

For instance, i'm looking for the complete specification for `<service_fmri/>`, which `value` attributes are valid, etc.

Where can i find the complete specification for writing Solaris SMF manifests ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The DTD looks fine on my system.  The only attribute to service_fmri is "value".

```
<!--
  service_fmri

    This element defines a reference to a service FMRI (for either a
    service or an instance).

    Its attribute is

        value   The FMRI.
-->

<!ELEMENT service_fmri EMPTY>

<!ATTLIST service_fmri
        value           CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Oh...I see you wanted what are valid FMRI values.  Start at the smf(5) man page for that kind of reference.

Comment: The DTD is bad, because the value is note described. The manpage is empty about the value scheme, for example, there's nothing about the different URL schemes svc:// file:// etc. Hence my question.